# In jquery validation how to validate only one array field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am including jquery validation in my project. I have array field if select box. I want to validate only one array field. But i am getting validate for all array field. How to fix this in jquery validation. I have attached my code below . Thanks in advance

```
<select class="form-controltop" id="keyword" style="margin: 7px 4px 4px;" name="rolefield[]">
<option value="">City</option>
<option value="">state</option>
<option value="">country</option>
</select> 
<select class="form-controltop" id="keyword1" style="margin: 7px 4px 4px;" name="rolefield[]">
<option value="">Personal</option>
<option value="">Hole</option>
<option value="">Project</option>
</select>    
<select class="form-controltop" id="keyword2" style="margin: 7px 4px 4px;" name="rolefield[]">
<option value="">views</option>
<option value="">process</option>
<option value="">making</option>
</select>
```

Jquery validation:

```
$("#addCustomer").validate({
    debug: false,
        errorClass: "authError clearfix",
        errorElement: "span", 
         ignore: [],
    rules: {
            'rolefield[]': {
                    required: true,

            }


        },

         highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. sorry for not included. I uploaded my jquery script code

Comment: I want only one select box have to validate out of three. Can you please edit on my code

Answer (score 0):

To solve this we will have multiple ways to complete:

1. You can serach **select** tag using id like *$("#keyword").val() != ""*. But before that you have to modify tag as below.

```html
<select class="form-controltop" id="keyword" style="margin: 7px 4px 4px;" name="rolefield[]">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="City">City</option>
<option value="State">state</option>
<option value="Country">country</option>
</select>
```

2. Or you can use **JQuery selector** like *$("select:nth-child(1)")*, So it will give you 1st select tag.

Comment: All select have same name, please provide different-2 name, And as per DOM and browser rule as well, we should give same ID and Name for different-2 controls. Once you change name, it will work.